# System sometimes displays blinking cursor, won't boot when loading with acpi_backlight=vendor

Tags: boot, grub2, laptop, brightness, backlight

A couple months ago I started experiencing an issue where the system **occasionally** will not boot into the desktop environment and simply displays a blinking cursor. When this happens, there is just a black screen with a blinking underscore in the top left. Various keyboard shortcuts don't do much except for F11 shows a menu but will not let me select anything. I have to hold the power button and try again.

The funny thing is that there is no consistency. I frequently boot between Windows and Ubuntu so I restart often, and maybe 50% of the time, I will encounter the cursor, and will have to do a hard shutdown, and try again. Sometimes it boots normally, as long as it goes through the disk check process.

I discovered that if I edit /etc/default/grub from this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

to this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Then I don't seem to have any boot issues. However, and this is a big problem - I can't control the brightness on my laptop and it turns out to be too dim to be usable.

Computer is: HP Laptop Model 15-dy2085
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: what kernel version?

Comment: In what way can you not control the backlight? do your fn-keys work, and not the brightness applet? Or the other way around? or neither? see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight

Comment: Kernel version: 5.13.0-48-generic

Comment: @Esther: Fn keys don't work if I change grub to nomodeset, and the brightness app doesn't change anything either. If I have acpi-backlight=vendor on, then they both work just fine.

Comment: what about with neither "nomodeset"  nor "acpi_backlight" ?

Comment: @Esther, gave that a try, and it booted properly 3 times in a row. Then I booted into Windows and then back into Ubuntu and it took 4x reboots before it would show me the login screen.

Comment: do you have "fast startup" turned off in Windows? It can cause problems with booting other OSes because Windows never really shuts down when fast startup is enabled.

Comment: Just to follow up on this for anyone reading. I did two things that seemed to fix it. 1. I cleared out disk space and corrected file system errors. 2. Upgraded to Ubuntu 22. I haven't had any issues since. I noticed that previously, it only booted once I got a message saying file system clean, so I think there may have been some file system issues preventing a proper boot.